# How to remove the duplicate from inner list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Below is the model class

```java
public class Employee {
    private int empId;
    private Components components;
}

public class Components{
    private int cmpid;
    private String cmpName;
}
```

Below is the Json response which I got from Database

```json
{
  "Employee": [
    {
      "empId": 30594,      
      "components": {
        "cmpid": 1,
        "cmpName": "ABC"
      }
    },
    {
      "empId": 30594,      
      "components": {
        "cmpid": 1,
        "cmpName": "ABC"
      }
    },
    {
      "empId": 30594,      
      "components": {
        "cmpid": 2,
        "cmpName": "BCD"
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert in to the below Object (remove the component object if duplicate example componenetid 1 and name ABC )

```java
public class EmployeeConverter {

    private int employeeID
    List<Components> components
}
```

```json
{
  "EmployeeConverter": [
    {
      "empId": 30594,      
      "components": {
        "cmpid": 1,
        "cmpName": "ABC"
      },
      "components": {
        "cmpid": 2,
        "cmpName": "BCD"
      }                
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to achieve using the for loop by going through each record but just wanted to check if there is there any way to achieve using the java8

Comment: Please fix your question, your Employee class won't compile as it has not types for its fields

Comment: Why is that class called `Components` if it encapsulates *one* entity?

Comment: Use a set instead of a list and make equals/hashCode look at empId.

Comment: You still don't have the right code posted. You can't "convert" a single employee with a *collection* of the class you wrongly call `Components` since an employee only has one according to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try library *Josson* to transform the JSON and remove the duplicate by function `group()`.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"Employee\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"empId\": 30594," +
    "      \"components\": {" +
    "        \"cmpid\": 1," +
    "        \"cmpName\": \"ABC\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"empId\": 30594," +
    "      \"components\": {" +
    "        \"cmpid\": 1," +
    "        \"cmpName\": \"ABC\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"empId\": 30594," +
    "      \"components\": {" +
    "        \"cmpid\": 2," +
    "        \"cmpName\": \"BCD\"" +
    "      }" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(EmployeeConverter:" +
    "        Employee" +
    "        .group(empId,components)" +
    "        .field(components" +
    "               .group(cmpid,cmpName)" +
    "               .field(cmpName[0])" +
    "         )" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "EmployeeConverter" : [ {
    "empId" : 30594,
    "components" : [ {
      "cmpid" : 1,
      "cmpName" : "ABC"
    }, {
      "cmpid" : 2,
      "cmpName" : "BCD"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should change your expected result, because it contains a collection of elements and not one property twice (hard to perform that in Java):

```json
{
  "convertedEmployees": [
    {
      "empId": 30594,
      "components": [
        {
          "cmpId": 1,
          "cmpName": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "cmpId": 2,
          "cmpName": "BCD"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The Java classes to achieve this (please separate them into individual files,  add annotations as appropriate and set visibility as private as possible):

```java
class Root {
  Set<EmployeeConverter> convertedEmployees = new HashSet<>();
}

class EmployeeConverter {
  int empId;
  Set<Component> components = new HashSet<>();

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return empId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    EmployeeConverter employeeConverter = (EmployeeConverter) o;
    return empId == employeeConverter.empId;
  }
}

class Component {
  int cmpId;
  String cmpName;

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return cmpId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Component component = (Component) o;
    return cmpId == component.cmpId;
  }
}
```

The outer `Root` class is necessary because the outer object also has a property `convertedEmployees` that is already a collection. I made all of your collections actually sets because you want to deduplicate contents. For this it is necessary to provide proper `equals` and `hashcode` implementations (they always have to go together) - you can let them generate in most IDEs that are a bit specialized on Java. I distinguished just by the IDs, not by the other content in my implementation, since that's what seems appropriate for your requirements.

When you now put multiple `Component`s into one `EmployeeConverter` they will automatically be deduplicated. Also when you put multiple `EmployeeConverter`s into the `Root`.

As I'm not sure about how you read in the JSON, `Map`s with the ID as key could be better suited instead of the `Set`s.